# how to get tomcat JAVA_OPTS from command line?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, command-line

I have a tomcat 6 running on windows 7. I have recently increased permSize, maxSize etc in catalina.sh file and I want to see if tomcat get the new options correctly, how can I see tomcat JAVA_OPTS from command line?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see your environment settings for Tomcat, run the following from the bin folder of your CATALINA_HOME.

```
catalina version
```

If everything is fine, you will see something similar:

```
D:\apache-tomcat-7.0\bin>catalina version
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\apache-tomcat-
7.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
Server built:   Jun 6 2013 11:16:08
Server number:  7.0.41.0
OS Name:        Windows 7
OS Version:     6.1
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_25-b17
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: I can't understand from this answer where the JAVA_OPTS are displayed.

Comment: @sgargel Try 'catalina configtest' command

Answer (score 0):

The file catalina.sh is meant to be used in Unix environments, use the catalina.bat instead.